# How to determine one to one relationship?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the first `Announcements` model:

```
class Announcements(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'announcements'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    duplicate = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    advert_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    rotate_photo = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    account = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
```

And `Account` model:

```
class Accounts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
```

A need to set one to one relationship between these models `Announcements` and `Account`  by bind: `Announcements.account = Account.id`

I tried this:

```
class Announcements(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'announcements'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account = db.Column(db.Integer(), ForeignKey('account.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = db.relationship("Account", back_populates="child")


class Accounts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    child = db.relationship("Announcements", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")
```

It gives me an error:

> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line
>   2100, in _determine_joins
>       "specify a 'primaryjoin' expression." % self.prop) sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship Accounts.child - there are
>   no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns
>   are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a
>   'primaryjoin' expression.

Comment: It is not clear

Comment: Look my question again, I did some attempts

Comment: The error is very clear: "there are no foreign keys linking these tables". Your foreign key in the Announcements model references the id column of **account**, while the Accounts model's table is named **accounts**. As such this is closable as a simple typo.